# Redux state to replace React Component internal state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'd like to implement a redux store in multiple components of my web app. Basically, I want to migrate what currently is internal state to redux.

I'm using a simple radio as an example.

**File without redux (only internal state):**

```js
// file Bool.js

import React from 'react';
import {FormControlLabel, Grid, Radio, RadioGroup} from "@material-ui/core";

class Bool extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bool: 'and'
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange = (evt) => {
    this.setState({
      bool: evt.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>

      <RadioGroup
        row
        value={this.state.bool}
        onChange={this.handleChange}>

      <Grid
        container
        direction="row"
        justify="center"
        alignItems="center">
      <FormControlLabel
        value="and"
        control={<Radio
          color="primary"/>}
        label="And"
        labelPlacement="end"/>
      <FormControlLabel
        value="or"
        control={<Radio
          color="primary"/>}
        label="Or"
        labelPlacement="end"/>
      </Grid>
      </RadioGroup>

      </div>
    )
  };
}

export default Bool
```

**File with redux:**

```js
// file Bool.js

import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {FormControlLabel, Grid, Radio, RadioGroup} from "@material-ui/core";
import {handleBool} from './Action_bool'

export class Bool extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bool: 'and'
    };
    this.handleBool = this.handleBool.bind(this)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>

      <RadioGroup
        row
        value={this.state.bool}
        onChange={this.handleBool}>

      <Grid
        container
        direction="row"
        justify="center"
        alignItems="center">
      <FormControlLabel
        value="and"
        control={<Radio
          color="primary"/>}
        label="And"
        labelPlacement="end"/>
      <FormControlLabel
        value="or"
        control={<Radio
          color="primary"/>}
        label="Or"
        labelPlacement="end"/>
      </Grid>
      </RadioGroup>

      </div>
    )
  };
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    bool: state
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {handleBool})(Bool);
```

**Action:**

```js
// file Action_bool.js

export function handleBool(value) {
  return ({
    type: 'HANDLE_BOOL_CHANGE',
    payload: value
  });
}
```

**Reducer:**

```js
// file Reducer_bool

const Reducer_bool = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'HANDLE_BOOL_CHANGE':
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default Reducer_bool
```

**Combine reducers:**

```js
// file Combine_reducers

import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import Reducer_bool from './Reducer_bool';

export default combineReducers({
  bool: Reducer_bool
});
```

**Index file:**

```js
// file index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {Box, CssBaseline, MuiThemeProvider} from "@material-ui/core";
import theme from './Standalone/theme';
import Bool from './Standalone/Bool';
import combineReducers from './Reducer_bool'

let store = createStore(combineReducers)

ReactDOM.render (
  <Provider
    store={store}>
  <MuiThemeProvider
    theme={theme}>
  <CssBaseline/>
  <Bool/>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
  )
```

**Error:**

TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

```
10 |    this.state = {
11 |      bool: 'and'
12 |    };
13 |    this.handleBool = this.handleBool.bind(this)
| ^  14 |  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can discard your bind to `handleBool` in the constructor

Instead use an arrow function on your  `onChange` attribute:

```
<RadioGroup
        row
        value={this.state.bool}
        onChange={({ value })) => this.props.handleBool(value)}> // this is the action from redux
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in the line your error is coming from is searching for a function in the context of the current class. Since the class does not have a function `handleBool`, neither will `this` and it will be undefined.

Like @jank's answer already says, you need to use the `handleBool` present in `this.props`. `connect` has automatically bound it to the dispatch function and added it to your props object.

Remove this line completely `this.handleBool= this.handleBool.bind(this)`.

And you can add a local function like this so that `onChange={this.handleBool}` will work as expected.

```js
handleBool= (evt) => {
  this.props.handleBool(evt.target.value);
}
```